# because when I import this camel-jaxb library all marshall works differently

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel, spring-camel, package-info

**Context**
When I don't import this library (org.apache.camel - camel-jaxb), the code performs the conversions normally from json to pojo, pojo to xml and xml to pojo,
but i want to use javax annotations for namespace and xsd

sample repository with included json file
[repository link github](https://github.com/NIkolaiSof/XmlToPojo)

[image: library camel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5OGc.png)
json to pojo - pojo to xml - xml to pojo

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
          <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
        from("file:file/json").to("direct:my-activemq-xml-queue");

        from("direct:my-activemq-xml-queue").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, CurrencyExchange.class)
                .to("bean-validator://x?group=javax.validation.groups.Default")
                .log("${body} ::::::::::::::::pojo:::::::::::::::").marshal().jacksonxml(CurrencyExchange.class)
                .log("${body} :::::::::::::::::::::xml:::::::::::::::::").to("direct:my-activemq-xml-json-queue");

        // converto xml to pojo
        from("direct:my-activemq-xml-json-queue").unmarshal().jacksonxml(CurrencyExchange.class)
                .to("log:received-message-from-active-mq");
```

[image: Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ccW.png)

**normal conversions**

[image: I move the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ZKV.png)

when I move the file it works normal but it doesn't bring me name space and xsd but it works normal

[image: normal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nljvs.png)

```
2021-03-31 11:58:45.031  INFO 33552 --- [ile://file/json] route2                                   : CurrencyExchange [id=1002, from=user@gmail.com, to=DRAFT, conversionMultiple=10, bool=true, table=table [key=userg@mail.com, value=cc]] ::::::pojo::::
2021-03-31 11:58:45.093  INFO 33552 --- [ile://file/json] route2                                   : <CurrencyExchange><id>1002</id><from>user@gmail.com</from><to>DRAFT</to><conversionMultiple>10</conversionMultiple><bool>true</bool><table><key>userg@mail.com</key><value>cc</value></table></CurrencyExchange> :::xml:
2021-03-31 11:58:45.160  INFO 33552 --- [ile://file/json] received-message-from-active-mq          : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: com.cam.camelmicroservicesb.routes.dto.response.CurrencyExchange, Body: CurrencyExchange [id=1002, from=user@gmail.com, to=DRAFT, conversionMultiple=10, bool=true, table=table [key=userg@mail.com, value=cc]]]
```

**Error**
But when I import this library, all the conversions are generated in xml

[image: import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjMsy.png)

[image: wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6apIS.png)

```
2021-03-31 11:30:51.012[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m34556[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ile://file/json][0;39m [36mroute2                                  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:currencyExchange xmlns:NS2="http://www.test.com/testml" xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/testxml">
    <ns2:id>1002</ns2:id>
    <ns2:From>user@gmail.com</ns2:From>
    <ns2:to>DRAFT</ns2:to>
    <ns2:ConversionMultiple>10</ns2:ConversionMultiple>
    <ns2:bool>true</ns2:bool>
    <ns2:table>
        <keyRequest>userg@mail.com</keyRequest>
        <valuePcRequest>cc</valuePcRequest>
    </ns2:table>
</ns2:currencyExchange>
 ::::::::::::::::pojo:::::::::::::::
[2m2021-03-31 11:30:51.061[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m34556[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ile://file/json][0;39m [36mroute2                                  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m <CurrencyExchange><id>1002</id><from>user@gmail.com</from><to>DRAFT</to><conversionMultiple>10</conversionMultiple><bool>true</bool><table><key>userg@mail.com</key><value>cc</value></table></CurrencyExchange> :::::::::::::::::::::xml:::::::::::::::::
[2m2021-03-31 11:30:51.114[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m34556[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ile://file/json][0;39m [36mreceived-message-from-active-mq         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: com.cam.camelmicroservicesb.routes.dto.response.CurrencyExchange, Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:currencyExchange xmlns:NS2="http://www.test.com/testml" xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/testxml">
    <ns2:id>1002</ns2:id>
    <ns2:From>user@gmail.com</ns2:From>
    <ns2:to>DRAFT</ns2:to>
    <ns2:ConversionMultiple>10</ns2:ConversionMultiple>
    <ns2:bool>true</ns2:bool>
    <ns2:table>
        <keyRequest>userg@mail.com</keyRequest>
        <valuePcRequest>cc</valuePcRequest>
    </ns2:table>
</ns2:currencyExchange>
]
```

Comment: Do you really need all camel-jaxb library? May be jaxb-core is sufficient?

Comment: Well, I'll try that one I had no knowledge and I'll tell you how it works. camel just mentioned jaxb